# Get two letter continent code from ip address with JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, geoip

I'm writing a JavaScript/Node.js application that needs to place items in a continent based on an IP address I receive. PHP has a [geoip_continent_code_by_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-continent-code-by-name.php) function which does exactly what I want except, of course, it's in PHP. Does anybody know of a JavaScript equivalent for this? It doesn't need to do any fancy address to latitude/longitude or similar things. It could be a standalone library, an NPM module, anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function uses the [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com) databases. Maxmind also provide Node.js and Javascript libraries for their databases [here](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/downloadable)

Comment: That's the one! Great. I ended up using the [geoip-lite](https://github.com/bluesmoon/node-geoip) npm module, which is a native JavaScript implementation of the MaxMind API.